# Autoposting to facebook company page in php

Tags: php, facebook

Ok, I know I am asking a question that has been asked thousands of times before, BUT I have not found an example or answer to my exact question.  Any information or help is greatly appreciated.

So, here is my need:

I have a company page for a website.  I created a facebook "app" so that I could get the app ID and key because I want the company website to be able to auto-post to the company page.  For example, if the website admin gives a badge to someone, it would automatically make a post to the company page that the app is for and say, "This bad was awarded to this person."

The thing is, I do NOT want the website admin to have to log into facebook to do this.  I want the website code to do everything.  Is there a way for the facebook app to be owned by the company page so that it can always make posts automatically to the company page?  Or is there no way of getting around the company page owner signing into facebook through the website?

Any informational links and examples would really help here too.  So again, the goal is for the website, without any person signing in, to make a post to the company page.  Thanks again~

Comment: Someone has to log in to facebook to get an `access_token`. That `access_token` is required to post to a facebook wall. After you have that access_token you don't need to be logged in all the time you want to post to the wall.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap Is that access token reusable, or only good for a certain period of time?  For instance, could I have them log in once, get the access token, save it to a database, then just use it from then on?

Comment: exactly. You have to save it and then you can use it at any time. When I remember it correctly an access_token can expire.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap I'm sorry, I'm a little confused.  Do you mean that I could save it but that eventually it will expire and they will need to log in again?  Also, I was needing to make posts while the person who actually signed in is not necessarily still online.  Would that saved access_token still work?

Comment: Yep the access_token would work if the person who gave that token is offline if you use the correct permissions when asking facebook for a token. And as I told you I can't remember if it really will expire and if it does the any person who owns the app or is assigned to it should be able to create a new one.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap Ok, I'll give that a try.  Thanks for your comments, and I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: You will need to first get a user access token and then exchange it for a long-lived access token with `manage_pages` permissions.  Then you can post to the Page using the token.  More info: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13113528/how-to-post-facebook-user-wall-page-status-by-a-single-user-only-no-app-install/13114174#13114174

Comment: @DonnLee Wow that is awesome information!  I'm surprised you guys are writing these up as answers.  :)  This is definitely the one I will try.  Thanks!

Comment: @DonnLee Thank you very very much.  That was exactly what I was looking for.  Can you make your comment into an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @James: promoted to an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why there is a down vote on the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first get a user access token and then exchange it for a long-lived access token with `manage_pages` permissions. Then you can post to the Page using the token.

More info:

[how to post facebook user wall/ page status by a single user only no app install for other users](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13113528/how-to-post-facebook-user-wall-page-status-by-a-single-user-only-no-app-install/13114174#13114174)

You will have to refresh the long-lived token every 60-days.